# Python regex remove spaces only between two 1 letter words

Tags: python, regex

I try write a code that behave like that:

input: "a b ccc" -> "ab ccc"

input: "aa bb" -> "aa bb"

input: "aa bb c d" -> "aa bb cd"

I succeed to write a regexp template which finds "a b" case but I don't sure how delete the space only.
This is my try:

```
import re
sentence = "a b cc"
print(sentence)
pattern = re.compile(r'[^\s]{1}\s[^\s]{1}')
sentence = re.sub(pattern, 'xx', sentence)
print(sentence)
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me how the input maps on the output... You want to remove the spaces after a 1 letter word?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want

Comment: what if you have `'a b c d'`. Do you want to join it like `'ab cd'`? Or `'abcd'`? The specs are not complete in my opinion.

Comment: 'a b c d' --> 'abcd'
'a b c d eee' --> 'abcd eee'

Comment: `'d eee'` --> ?

Comment: And simply `'a'`? I know this is probably annoying, but right now there are a lot of different solutions.

Comment: I want delete spaces only between two words of 1 length each

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to match those words with

```
\b([a-z]) (?=[a-z]\b)
```

and then replace with

```
\g<1>
```

This will match a single letter word (ensured by the word boundary) and capture it. Then match a space and ensure that this is followed by another single letter word. The replacement is the first captured group.

In [Python](http://ideone.com/lVX2f6)

```
import re
sentence = "a b cc e ddd f g h"
pattern = re.compile(r'\b([a-z]) (?=[a-z]\b)', re.I)
sentence = re.sub(pattern, r'\g<1>', sentence)
print(sentence)
```

Will output `ab cc e ddd fgh`

See also https://regex101.com/r/y2chHw/1

Comment: Just FYI: `\g<1>` can be replaced with `r'\1'` in the `re.sub` call. Since there is no ambiguity here, `\1` will work well, too.